# Bad nmap grepable output

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, nmap, port-scanning

if i scan which nmap one target and i use output grepable option (-oG) if have this output

```
nmap -sS -oG - 192.168.1.1
Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.1 ()  Ports: 20/closed/tcp//ftp-data///, 21/open/tcp//ftp///, 22/closed/tcp//ssh///, 43/closed/tcp//whois///, 80/open/tcp//http///
# Nmap done at Thu Dec 12 11:32:36 2
```

As you can see the line who indicate the ports number have no newline. For use grep it's no easy... :)

I'am on debian wheezy, i use bash, how can i correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, although they call it "grepable" output, it's more meant to be parsed by tools such as awk, sed or Perl.

Alot of useful information is on [NMAP website](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html#output-formats-ex-grepable-scanme).

The fields are also separated by tab characters, so i'd start with eg. `cut -f5 file` to get the fields you want and then you can do fine parsing with say `awk -F/ '{print $2}'`. I'm not sure what part of the output is of interest.

Perl would also work to parse the output as described on their webpage, but that's probably not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I wan to juste print port list, i use awk to filtre, but it can't run, because port list ouptut as print on one line


# nmap -sS -oG - 192.168.1.1 | awk -F/ '{print $2}'


open

#

I search to correct this output:

Host: 192.168.1.1 ()  Ports: 20/closed/tcp//ftp-data///, 21/open/tcp//ftp///, 22/closed/tcp//ssh///, 43/closed/tcp//whois///, 80/open/tcp//http///

to

Host: 192.168.1.1 ()  Ports: 
20/closed/tcp//ftp-data///, 
21/open/tcp//ftp///, 
22/closed/tcp//ssh///, 
43/closed/tcp//whois///, 
80/open/tcp//http///

Probably a terminal or environnement problem?

Comment: You can also pipe the NMAP's output to | tr '\t' '\n' to replace tabs with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that output. [Grepable format](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) is designed to have one line per host, so that you can grep for all hosts with a particular port open.

If what you want is a list of only those ports that are open, you can tell Nmap to only print those with the [`--open`](http://nmap.org/book/man-output.html#idm226643119584) option:

```
sh$ nmap -p 80,22 localhost -oG - -n -Pn --open
# Nmap 6.41SVN scan initiated Thu Dec 12 08:40:03 2013 as: nmap -p 80,22 -oG - -n -Pn --open localhost
Host: 127.0.0.1 ()  Status: Up
Host: 127.0.0.1 ()  Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///  Ignored State: closed (1)
# Nmap done at Thu Dec 12 08:40:03 2013 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```